# What is the target of "__pthread_spinlock_t __held" in "struct __pthread_mutex"?

Tags: pthreads

Why is there a spinlock in pthread_mutex ?https://github.com/ragingwind/libpthread/blob/master/sysdeps/generic/bits/mutex.h#L40

```
/* User visible part of a mutex.  */
struct __pthread_mutex
  {
    __pthread_spinlock_t __held;
    __pthread_spinlock_t __lock;
    /* In cthreads, mutex_init does not initialized thre third
       pointer, as such, we cannot rely on its value for anything.  */
    char *cthreadscompat1;
    struct __pthread *__queue;
    struct __pthread_mutexattr *attr;
    void *data;
    /*  Up to this point, we are completely compatible with cthreads
    and what libc expects.  */
    void *owner;
    unsigned locks;
    /* If NULL then the default attributes apply.  */
  };
```

It does here https://github.com/ragingwind/libpthread/blob/master/sysdeps/generic/pt-mutex-unlock.c#L98

```
/* Unlock MUTEX, rescheduling a waiting thread.  */
int
__pthread_mutex_unlock (pthread_mutex_t *mutex)
...
  /* We do not unlock MUTEX->held: we are transferring the ownership
     to the thread that we are waking up.  */
```

Comment: "*Why is there a spinlock in pthread_mutex ?*" -- why shouldn't there be?  And what kind of answer are you hoping for, other than "that's how that implementation does it"?

Comment: yes. question could be: why does that implementation do it...